# list.toArray() agrees to transfer items of type A to an array of type B[]

Tags: java, arrays, list, generics

I have the following code:

```
private double doThings(List<ClassA> list){
    ClassB[] array = list.toArray(new ClassB[0]);
    // ...
}
```

This compiles. Why?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray(T[]) ArrayStoreException - if the runtime type of the specified array is not a supertype of the runtime type of every element in this list.

Comment: @Nambari I see. You might want to make that an answer. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray(T%5B%5D)):

`ArrayStoreException` - if the runtime type of the specified array is not a supertype of the runtime type of every element in this list.

Answer (score 1):

java.util.List source code is interesting:

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/List.java

The class is generic by the type :

```
public interface List<E> extends Collection<E>
```

However, toArray method is parametrized by a different type :

```
<T> T[] toArray(T[] a);
```

This is a generic method using a different type as a parameter than the class itself. There's no link between T and E. That's why you can use different types for the argument in toArray method than the class that was used to parametrize the list.

It would be interesting to find the reasoning behind this design. On first look, it's a bit strange.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way the method can be declared that will prevent the possibility of `ArrayStoreException`. Even if the method were declared to have parameter type `A[]`, you can still pass it an array whose runtime type is `SubClassOfA[]`, and if the list has `A` objects, then it will cause an `ArrayStoreException` because they cannot be stored in a `SubClassOfA[]`.

Since there is no way to avoid it, and it depends on the programmer to use it properly, they might as well make the method as general as possible, and take any type of array. When used correctly (i.e. when we know that all objects are also instances of `B`), it will not cause an `ArrayStoreException`.